# fread and fwrite parameters in C

Tags: c, matlab, moving-average

I am trying to adapt a matlab program to C, my problem is in the `fwrite` and `fread` function. On matlab I have:

```
fid = fopen ('sweep_100_3400.pcm','rb');
s = fread (fid, 'int16');
```

My doubt is, in C there are two more parameters in `fread` and `fwrite` function.

```
fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*);
fwrite(const void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*);
```

In my C code I have:

```
arq = fopen("C:\\Users\\iago_\\Desktop\\MediaMovel\\sweep_100_3400.pcm", "rb");
fread(x, sizeof(double), itera, arq);
fclose(arq);
```

`x` is the vector where the data of my file will be saved.
`sizeof(double)` is the length of the data (I've declared all `double`)
`arq` is the pointer to the file.

**The third parameter is a `size_t`, to adapt my matlab program, in this parameter should I use the media length or the vector size?**

(I am encoding a moving average, the media length is informed by the user and the vector size is the length of my input file).

For the `fwrite` function I have the same doubt about the parameters.

```
arq=fopen("C:\\Users\\iago_\\Desktop\\MediaMovel\\saida_medial_movel_c.pcm", "wb");
fwrite(saida, sizeof(double), itera, arq);
fclose(arq);
```

Comment: The `size` and `count` arguments for `fread`, when multiplied, must be no larger than the receiving buffer size. A read of the man page will help you. Also, the return value from `fread` is significant, since the requested amount of data may not have been available.

Comment: Post the definition of `saida` and how the value of `itera` is derived to better present the question.

Comment: Your aim is unclear, but if you are trying to write the data you read from one file with `fread` to another with `fwrite`, then the `count` argument for `fwrite` must be the return value from `fread` - the number of elements of size `size` that were read.

Answer (score 0):

fread() parameters are

```
size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);
```

where nmemb is multiple of size function of read. So second parameter should be sizeof your vector and third should number of vectors you want to read from file pointer. Also there is but of confusion about matlab fread call. second param in matlab fread call is int16 which is 2 bytes, but in c fread call you have passed second param as sizeof(double) which is 8 bytes.

Comment: `sizeof(double)` is not guaranteed to be 8 bytes. Can be 1, 2, etc., depending on `CHAR_BIT` and the memory required for a `double`. Similar for `int16`: it can be `1` or `2`.

Comment: I solved the problem using short type in my x vector instead double, with that works.